# Extracting Tables From Different Sites With BeautifulSoup IN A LOOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have extracted a table from a site with the help of BeautifulSoup. Now I want to keep this process going in a loop with several different URL:s. If it is possible, I would like to extract these tables into different excel documents, or different sheets within a document.

I have been trying to put the code through a loop and appending the df

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'path/to/file.xlsx')
link = xl.parse('Sheet1') 

#this is what I can't figure out
for i in range(0,10):
    try:
        url = link['Link'][i]

        html = requests.get(url).content

        df_list = pd.read_html(html)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        table = soup.select_one('table:contains("Fees Earned")')

        df = pd.read_html(str(table))
        list1.append(df)

    except ValueError:
    print('Value')
    pass

#Not as important
a = df[0]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('mytables.xlsx')
a.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I get a 'ValueError'(no tables found) for the first nine tables and only the last table is printed when I print mylist. However, when I print them without the for loop, one link at a time, it works.
I can't append the value of df[i] because it says 'index out of range'

Comment: valueError could be many things... the interpreter will tell you which line of code was the reason you ran into that error.  For why only one table comes through, it's because you're writing to your excel outside of the for loop, and you're not appending any data to your dataframe... just creating new ones each time you get the web content.

Comment: No, I did not mean to excel. If I create a list and append the values, only the last one gets printed- the others simply say "table not found". When I run each of them alone however, it works.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I updated the code to how it actually looks now and tried to clarify the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that means that no table was found then.  maybe theres an issue with how you're iterating over the urls.  In python, I would avoid looping with range, and instead loop over the urls themselves e.g. `for url in urls:`  Other than that I'm not sure how to help... you make reference to mylist, which I assume is list1?  Either way, aim to be super clear about what errors are being thrown, and what variables are causing the problems.  Writing down the entire error message for example is totally fine here.

Comment: Thank you or your help! The problem was that the keyword was too specific and there simply was no table to be found.

Comment: No problem.  for the future, it's a bit frustrating that you mentioned: "However, when I print them without the for loop, one link at a time, it works." That means that this wasn't actually true.  If you're asking for people to advise on an issue,  make sure you spend the time to make sure everything you write is fully tested and known to be true.